# Making a block to show the status of the user account?

Tags: users

How do I use a Views block (or other means) to show the status of the user account, specifically awaiting approval, approved, and not approved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pending User Notification Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/pending_user_notification)

> This module is for sites that allow users to create an account, but
>   require administrator approval for account activation. This module
>   creates a block that shows a list of unactivated user accounts, with
>   links to their account pages. This block is visible for anyone with
>   'administer users' permission, and will not be shown to any other
>   users.